# NLTK corpora : IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus

Here when I run this particular code

```
import os
import nltk
import nltk.corpus
print(os.listdir(nltk.data.find("corpora"))) `
```

I get

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: show code which you run - you shouldn't get this error for this line of code. You may have error in different place.

Comment: @furas  I have written only four line in which three of them are importing the library.

Comment: I run this code without error. If there is problem with data then you should get this error   also with two lines: `import nltk` , `print(nltk.data.find("corpora"))`. As I rember `nltk` may need to download data from server but I don't know if it does it automatically or you have to manuallu run `nltk.download()`

Comment: Thanks man @furas I solved the problem, the problem was related to data when I ran nltk.download(). the error has been gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run this code without error.

If there is problem with data then you should get this error also with two lines:

```
import nltk 

print(nltk.data.find("corpora"))
```

As I remember `nltk` at start needs to download data from server - and this can be the problem.

```
import nltk 

nltk.download()
```

See doc: [Installing NLTK Data](https://www.nltk.org/data.html)

Comment: Can you please explain how nltk.download() work in NLP

Comment: it is complex function - see [source code](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/5023d6b933ef1a5b1f25fba1d5ed11a8a43a47e4/nltk/downloader.py#L745). Sortly: It uses `urllib.request` and [url in code](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/5023d6b933ef1a5b1f25fba1d5ed11a8a43a47e4/nltk/downloader.py#L457) to download it.